# Run() AutoIt does not work in Windows x64

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, autoit

**Task:** Write a program that simply displays 3 buttons when clicked on, which simulates pressing a key combination (macros Ctrl+Z) in another window. I developed app in windows x32 and tried to run in windows x64

**What I did:** My code:

```vb
Imports AutoItX3Lib

Imports System.Configuration

Public Class Form1
    Dim AutoitCommand As New AutoItX3
    'get setting in app.config. C:\Users\mexal\AppData\Local\Figma\Figma.exe
    Dim RouteExe As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RouteExe")
    'get setting in app.config. "name - Figma" name - name document that to be opened
    Dim WindowName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WindowName")

    Public Sub New()

        'init form
        InitializeComponent()

        'set top position
        TopMost = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonUndo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUndo.Click

        AutoitCommand.Run(RouteExe)
        AutoitCommand.WinWaitActive(WindowName)
        AutoitCommand.Send("^z")

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonRrendo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRrendo.Click

        AutoitCommand.Run(RouteExe)
        AutoitCommand.WinWaitActive(WindowName)
        AutoitCommand.Send("^y")

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonSpace_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSpace.Click

        AutoitCommand.Run(RouteExe)
        AutoitCommand.WinWaitActive(WindowName)
        AutoitCommand.Send("{SPACE}")

    End Sub

End Class
```

**What's happened:** The app started after I installed AutoItX3Lib. Okay. But app crash when it wants to start app by path C:\Users\mexal\AppData\Local\Figma\Figma.exe and Figma.exe started but figma window didn't show and figma-app still working only in processes.

**Question** What I do wrong?:(

Comment: did not help ((

Comment: in x32 still workung fine, but in x64 any exe open without create window. (device Surface Book 2 if this important...)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite app in *.cs end it works fine!

Ex.:

```vb
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AutoItX3Lib;

namespace ArtistButtons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AutoItX3 auto = new AutoItX3();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void ctrlz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            auto.WinActivate("инста - Figma");
            auto.Send("^z");
        }
    }
}
```